# How do I configure AWS Application load balancer and NAT gateway to have the public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, devops, amazon-ecs, amazon-alb

so currently in our infrastructure we are using ECS with an application load balancer for inbound traffic and a NAT gateway for outbound traffic. I am looking to configure both inbound and outbound traffic to have the same public IP address but I am not sure how this is done as I've tried may different ways to achieve this but nothing seemed to have worked. If we take a look at the below image our infrastructure is similar except that we us EC2 and not fargate as we prefer to maintain our own instances

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WOaI.png)

I would be very thankful if anyone could please help me out with this

Comment: This isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think this is possible. External traffic is always routed though a NAT gateway, and incoming either though unknown number of ever changing load balancers or directly to IP of the e.g. EC2 instance.

Comment: Logically yes, its not possible but the diagram on the aws website seems to be configured that way which is very puzzling to me.

Comment: @BharathDundi Diagram must have mistake.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @BharathDundi The duplicate public IP in that diagram is a mistake. Please post a message at the feedback link at the bottom of the page you screenshotted.

Comment: Sure Mark I will do that, thank you for all your help